# get value of http request headers in php

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, http-headers

I am sending customer header in AJAX call,

```
$.ajaxSetup( {
     data: {csrf_token : csrf},
     headers: {"Csrf_token" : csrf}
    });
```

Below is content which i seen in Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:325
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:ci_session=kd817592v16s0p5b2f502hg39rs7olnu; csrf_cookie=22a1c908f3f036c90c2d0bf0f9b19497
Csrf_token:22a1c908f3f036c90c2d0bf0f9b19497
Host:testurl.com
Origin:http://testurl.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://testurl.com/xxx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

But when i print this in PHP it only return below, i could not see my custom header "Csrf_token"

```
> Array ( [X-Forwarded-For] => 57.73.33.1 [Cookie] =>
> `ci_session=kd817592v16s0p5b2f502hg39rs7olnu;
> csrf_cookie=22a1c908f3f036c90c2d0bf0f9b19497 [Accept-Language] =>
> en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6 [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
> [Referer] => http://testurl.com/xxx [X-Requested-With] =>
> XMLHttpRequest [Accept] => */* [Content-Type] =>
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 [User-Agent] =>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36 [Origin] =>
> http://testurl.com[Cache-Control] => no-cache [Pragma] => no-cache
> [Content-Length] => 325 [Connection] => close [Host] => testurl.com )`
```

How can i get that customer header in PHP? I am using codeigniter,

Comment: Can you post the output of `$_SERVER`

Answer (score 1):

I only got output by below,

```
$.ajaxSetup( {
     data: {csrf_token : csrf},
     headers: {"csrf-token" : csrf, "csrf_token1" : csrf}
    });
```

It will not print values with _ name but can print with - names.

Csrf-Token : "22a1c908f3f036werc90c2d0bf0f9b19497"

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$headers = $this->input->request_headers();
```

link : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get_request_header

Comment: that also doesn't print it

Comment: you set data for 'csrf_token'

Comment: check all params by print $_REQUEST

Comment: I get my solution, headers not working with _ but working with -